# Regex to pick a string which begins with 'TL' and has only 14 characters

Tags: regex

"0300002527
04/05/2019
TY DOC NO. BILL NO. DATE SP HEADER TEXT GROSS AMOUNT TDS AMOUNT(INR)
G2 0230302902 TL27T192
0/1854
02/05/2019 PACAHC19873
795
536414.00 -2273.00 534,141.00"

In the above string i want only 'TL27T192
0/1854'

Answer (score 0):

If your structure is fixed then you can use.

```
TL\d+T\d+\s*\d\/\d+
```

- /
     TL\d+T\d+\s*\d/\d+
     /
     gm
     TL matches the characters TL literally (case sensitive)
     \d+ matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

  - Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    T matches the character T literally (case sensitive)
    \d+ matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
  - Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    \s* matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
  - Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    \d matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
    / matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
    \d+ matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
  - Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Answer (score 0):

I've read better your request and tryed to figure out your requirements better
looks like that you want a string that starts with TL and is 14 symbols in total except counting the spaces

if this is the case then

```
TL *([^ ] *){12}
```

may fit your case. anyway a more precise reply will require more precise requirements on how the string you are searching can be formatted

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mose. It was very useful.

Comment: What shall i do if i want to ignore a new line? I mean lets say in that 'TL27T192 0/' is in the first and 1854 is in the next

Comment: you may try TL(?:[  \r\n])*([^ \r\n](?:[  \r\n])*){12} and then discard eventual CR and LF characters from the matched string or maybe the library you are using has an option to support multiline capture, please remember to upvote if the reply satisfly you

Answer (score 0):

[Exactly what you want](https://regex101.com/r/ik7MbE/1/):

```
TL.{14}
```